# Sign application using .p12 and .mobileprovision from 3rd party

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, enterprise, in-house-distribution

I need to sign app for Enterprise deployment. Customer's security department refused to add my apple ID to their team, thought they send me mobileprovision and p12 files. As far as I remember, in XCode 5 there was possibility to sign IPA without Apple ID using mobileprovision only, like that:
[Xcode5 - Enterprise deploy screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63kWS.png)

When I try to do it in XCode 7 or 8, I got error like [XCode 8 - Enterprise export error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT6oz.png) because my Apple ID is not registered in customer's enterprise team.

I've already added .p12 to keychain, unchecked "Automatically manage signing", selected customer's provisioning profile.

I try to use xcodebuild like `xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath <FILE_NAME>.xcarchive -exportPath ~/Desktop/<FILE_NAME>.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile <PROVISIONING PROFILE NAME>`, but still no success.

Also, I need to generate manifest file, that's why xcodebuild is rough solution even if it will work.

I know that its unusual when customer give cert and keypair, but dont want to add developer to team, but cannot change it. 
How can I export build for Enterprise if I have provision and certificate, but my account is not in team?

Comment: xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE -scheme SCHEME archive -archivePath PATH.xcarchive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath PATH.xcarchive -exportPath PATH -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile PROVISIONINGPROFILE

generated ipa-file. That's work, but still I'm looking for autogenerating manifest file

Comment: You can just type your manifest file manually, here are examples, also check out the correct url link to use that contains 'itms-services': https://gist.github.com/hramos/774468    Also that command you used, I've been using for last few years and in last few days it got broken. I think the command line got updated, it now requires an 'optionsPlist' and when I added that I got the same warning you were getting in xCode in command line too.